# Failed to detect a valid hadoop home directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have set up Hadoop 2.2.0 single node and started it up. I am able to browse the FS on `http://localhost:50070/`
Then I tried to write a dummy file using the following code.

```
public class Test {
public void write(File file) throws IOException{
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    Path outFile = new Path("test.jpg");       
    FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(outFile);        

}
```

I get the following exception

```
INFO:   DEBUG - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
    INFO:   DEBUG - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
    INFO:   DEBUG - UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
    INFO:   DEBUG -  Creating new Groups object
    INFO:   DEBUG - Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
    INFO:   DEBUG - Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
    INFO:   DEBUG - java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
    INFO:   WARN - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    INFO:   DEBUG - Falling back to shell based
    INFO:   DEBUG - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
    INFO:   DEBUG - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000
    INFO:   DEBUG - hadoop login
    INFO:   DEBUG - hadoop login commit
    INFO:   DEBUG - using local user:UnixPrincipal: qualebs
    INFO:   DEBUG - UGI loginUser:qualebs (auth:SIMPLE)
    INFO:   DEBUG - Failed to detect a valid hadoop home directory
    java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:250)
        at 
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:772)
        at com.qualebs.managers.HadoopDFS.writer(HadoopDFS.java:41)
```

Where do I set the HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir?
Operating system is Ubuntu 11.10

The only configuration files I have configured are the following with the properties added

1. core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

2. hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

3. mapred-site.xml.template

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Eagerly awaiting your responses.

Comment: Could you please show me the complete trace??

Comment: @Tariq sorry for the late response, my problem is now fixed from reading your answer to this question www.stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840 apparently I was calling `FileSystem.get(new Configuration())` before adding the resources to the configuration.

Comment: No problem. Glad that you got it working :)

Comment: @Tariq if possible could you please point me to a good tutorial on how I can upload a file from a web page like an image or video into the hadoop file system and how to display this file file on a websites front end JSP page.

Answer (score 23):

I found my solution by doing this:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
```

This exception is thrown by [`checkHadoopHome()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.1.1-beta/org/apache/hadoop/util/Shell.java#Shell.checkHadoopHome%28%29) in `org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the differences between both solutions. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CamiloSampedro Sorry for the trouble, I've updated the solution. I forget another solution I used :(

Answer (score 1):

This set up is not working on the Windows. A workaround is to create a folder on your project (for example winutils/bin) and place the winutils.exe in it (see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems). Then in the Java code add

```
static {
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    if (OS.contains("win")) {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", Paths.get("winutils").toAbsolutePath().toString());
    } else {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
    }
  }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

add it to the terminal bash file if you are not using dedicated user for hadoop.

```
1. start terminal
2. sudo vi .bashrc
3. export HADOOP_HOME=YOUR_HADOOP_HOME_DIRECTORY(don't include bin folder)
4. save
5. restart terminal and check it if it's saved by typing : echo $HADOOP_HOME
```

Comment: I have added it but I'm still getting the same exception.  I have also tried creating a dedicate user account for hadoop, repeated the installation and ran some examples in the installation directory successfully the only problem is I am not able to write a file from my jsp web application in netbeans. where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you please edit the post with the current issue??

Comment: Nothing has changed the question remains as is. Is hadoop home directory the home directory in the hadoop file system or the directory containing the uncompressed hadoop tar file? when I `echo $HADOOP_HOME` the output is `/usr/local/hadoop`.

Comment: You are getting the right value. Well, I don't think I know why it's not working. but I can tell you a trick. Download the hadoop core jar and place it in the classpath. then run your application. Did you try this??

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same exact error messages from something, I don't believe is related to paths at all. I had my logger set improperly:

Was causing the error:

```
import org.apache.log4j._

trait Logger {
  val logger = LogManager.getRootLogger
}
```

Fixed it:

```
import org.apache.log4j._

trait Logger {
  val logger = LogManager.getRootLogger
  logger.setLevel(Level.INFO)
}
```

The solution might not at all be in changing the paths.

Comment: Reducing the log level only hides the error, doesn't solve it